# Print two patterns only when the second pattern occurs

Tags: awk, sed, text-processing

How can I print the name with Score only when person has English subject score.

In other word, grepping for 2 pattern and print first and second pattern only when 2nd pattern is matched.

**INPUT:**

```
            {
                "sessionId": "000001",
                "name": "ABC",
                "Age": "21",
                "Score": {
                    "English": "A+",
                    "Mathematics": "B-",
                    "String Theory": "C+"
                }
            },
            {
                "sessionId": "000001",
                "name": "CDE",
                "Age": "21",
                "Score": {
                    "English": "A-",
                    "German": "B-",
                    "French": "C+"
                }
            },
            {
                "sessionId": "000001",
                "name": "EFG",
                "Age": "21",
                "Score": {
                    "German": "A+",
                    "Mathematics": "B-",
                    "Machine Learning": "C+"
                }
            },
```

**OUTPUT**

```
"name": "ABC",
"English": "A",
"name": "CDE",
"English": "A",
```

Comment: This can certainly be done with sed, but I suspect the awk solution will be less cryptic...

Comment: And you mean to omit the +/- from the score?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input is actually a proper JSON array and not a fragment of one:

```
$ jq -r '.[] | select(.Score.English) | {name: .name, English: .Score.English} | @text' demo.json | sed 's/^{\|}$//g; s/,/\n/'
"name":"ABC"
"English":"A+"
"name":"CDE"
"English":"A-"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `awk` , in the first block leading spaces are removed. In the second block, if the line containing "name" is seen then store it to a variable named `name` and then if one of the following line contains `English` then print the earlier captured variable `name` along with the current line.

```
awk -F: '{sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")} /name/{name=$0} /English/{print   name ORS $0}'
"name": "ABC",
"English": "A+",
"name": "CDE",
"English": "A-",
```

Comment: FYI: This answer was flagged as low-quality, you may want to improve it.

Comment: @oguzismail ,thanks for pointing it out. Although wondering why most of the other answers are not marked same ?

Comment: No single idea. Maybe someone picking on you? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

another `awk` with little bit format checking

```
$ awk '/"name":/         {n=$0} 
       /"Score":/        {s=1} 
       s && /}/          {s=n=""} 
       s && /"English":/ {print n ORS $0}' file | awk '$1=$1'

"name": "ABC",
"English": "A+",
"name": "CDE",
"English": "A-",
```

checks whether "English" is in "Score" element.

Answer (score 0):

Sed solution:

```
sed -n 's/^ *//;/name/h;/English/{H;g;p;}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ jq 'select (.Score.English) | {name, English: .Score.English}' < <(sed 's/},/}/' file) | sed -n 's/^  *//p'
"name": "ABC",
"English": "A+"
"name": "CDE",
"English": "A-"
```

.

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]*,?[[:space:]]*$/,"")
    key = $1
    gsub(/^"|"[^"]*$/,"",key)
    f[key] = $0
}
key == "English" {
    print f["name"] ORS $0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"name": "ABC"
"English": "A+"
"name": "CDE"
"English": "A-"
```

With both of the above if in future you want to print anything else, e.g. `Age`, you just follow the existing pattern to add them to the list.

Comment: `name: .name` can be written as `name`, like `{name, English: .Score.English}`

Comment: @oguzismail thanks. Trying to learn `jq` but the syntax is a tad non-intuitive!

Comment: Ikr, it took me at least a month to understand how it works. You can study @peak's answers, he's like Jon Skeet of jq :D

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/name/h;/English/!b;H;g;s/^\s*//Mgp' file
```

Turn on optional printing by using the `-n` option.

Copy the line containing `name`.

Throw away lines that do not contain `English`.

Append the line containing `English` to the `name` line.

Replace the current line by the contents of the hold space.

Remove any white space at the start of either line and print the result.